# Как подключится к существующей базе данных в rails?

Tags: activerecord, ruby, firebird, ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток.
Есть готовая бд на firebird для проекта. Необходимо подключиться через Active record и получить все преимущества ORM (не писать sql-запросы). Возможна ли вообще автогенерация необходимых моделей в зависимости от конкретной структуры бд, учитывая связки, валидации и т.д.?
В дальнейшем планируется, что бд будет изменять человек, не имеющий ничего общего с ruby и rails. И стоит вопрос: возможно ли такое и как правильно осуществлять изменения?
Используются Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.1.0, Firebird 2.5.
Спасибо за внимание:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможна ли вообще автогенерация необходимых моделей в зависимости от конкретной структуры бд, учитывая связки, валидации и т.д.?

Сами классы моделей необходимо создавать руками, но атрибуты описывать не нужно. Нужно будет явно указать `table_name`, `primary_key`, если они отличаются от тех имён, к каким привык rails. Ещё, возможно, придётся переопределить `inheritance_column`, если в таблице используется столбец с именем `type`.

Также потребуется указать `foreign_key` и `class_name` явно для вызовов `has_many`, `has_one`, `belongs_to` и `has_and_belongs_to_many`, если правила именования столбцов другие, чем те, к которым привык rails.

А так всё будет работать -- сам работал со старой php-шной базой через ActiveRecord, предварительно так описав модели.